# Pause exoplayer by Default and response to the play/pause button

Tags: android, video-streaming, exoplayer2.x

After loading a video, it starts to play. 
I want the video to be paused for the very first time after loading. If the user clicks on the resume button it must start to play. How can I achieve this for exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView?

Comment: add code what you have tried .

Comment: Did you try `player.setPlayWhenReady(false)` ?

Comment: https://exoplayer.dev/listening-to-player-events.html

Answer (score 0):

> I want the video to be paused for the very first time after loading

You can use `player.setPlayWhenReady(false);` when you init your `Player`.

> If the user clicks on the resume button it must start to play.

You can add a `ControlDispatcher` in your `PlayView` by calling `setControlDispatcher(@Nullable ControlDispatcher controlDispatcher)` method, like `playerView.setControlDispatcher(new MyDefaultControlDispatcher());`

The class `MyDefaultControlDispatcher` is my Custom `ControlDispatcher`, as below:

```
private class MyDefaultControlDispatcher extends DefaultControlDispatcher {

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchSetPlayWhenReady(Player player, boolean playWhenReady) {
        super.dispatchSetPlayWhenReady(player, playWhenReady);
    if (playWhenReady && player.getPlaybackState() == Player.STATE_READY) {
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    }
        return true;
    }
}
```

You can inherit the `DefaultControlDispatcher` to `Override` your favorite method , like `dispatchSetPlayWhenReady`, **OR** implement the interface `ControlDispatcher`.

The method `dispatchSetPlayWhenReady` will get your click event on the play/stop button in your `PlayView`. You can verify it in your `PlayerControlView`'s `OnClick` method. I will show your picture as below:
[image]

**PS:** Like @ahmedaljubair has mentioned that the method `setPlayWhenReady` only work when the player is in the ready state. So, you need check the player's state when you call the `setPlayWhenReady` method to pause and resume your player.